# Mobius transforms - inversion sends line/circle -> line/circle

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, circles, mobius-transformation

I'm trying to prove that the inversion mapping $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ sends circles or lines to circles or lines.

Apparently the set $$\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z-a|^2 = r^2 \}$$ describes either a circle or a line.

How does this set includes circle and lines?

Circles are defined as $|z - a| = r$ and lines are defined as $|z-a| = |z-b|$?

Comment: Your set ls always a circle (possibly of radius $0$).

Comment: Strictly speaking, inversion is $z \to 1/\bar z$ in order that $O,M,M'$ are aligned. See paragraph 4 in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2626356

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That set describes a circle, not a line.

The function $f$ maps circles *which pass through the origin* into lines and all other circles into circles. It als maps line passing through the origin into lines and all other lines into circlse.

Consider, for instance, the line $\{t+(1-t)i\,|\,t\in\mathbb R\}$. For each $t\in\mathbb R$, you have$$\frac1{t+(1-t)i}=\frac{t+(t-1)i}{t^2+(1-t)^2}=\frac t{2t^2-2t+1}+\frac{t-1}{2t^2-2t+1}i$$and$$(\forall t\in\mathbb R):\left(\frac t{2t^2-2t+1}-\frac12\right)^2+\left(\frac{t-1}{2t^2-2t+1}+\frac12\right)^2=1.$$

Comment: However, my lecturer says that the complex representation of a line is $l = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: \overline{a} z + a\overline{z} = b, a \in \mathbb{C}, b \in \mathbb{R}\} $. Do you not get this if you write $|z-a|^2 = r^2 \Rightarrow (z-a)\overline{(z-a)} = r^2$ and expand? Edit: the latex isn't going my way (can't format set brackets) but hopefully you can see what I mean...

Comment: Do you expect me to reply saying the opposite of what I wrote in my answer? I wrote that $\{z\in\mathbb C\,|\,\lvert z-a\rvert^2=r^2\}$ is a circle, not a line, which is something that you can check for yourself.

Comment: ok it just that this was in an exam and I have a complex analysis exam today