# Reflection Over Planes in 3D

Tags: geometry, reflection

Reflecting a point over a flat plane in 3D is not super simple, but relatively simple and I have seen on stackexchange how matrices are used to figure out where the reflected point is projected.

However, throughout this I thought how could this be applied to curved planes like cones, spheres, parabola and more.

For example, say you have a generic line L1 [never intersects the plane with equation ax+by+cz+d=0] and L1 is reflected over said plane, where would L1 be projected to?

Also what would happen if this plane is now curved like a parabola in 3D? Is it possible to derive a single equation for this?

Comment: A "curved plane" is usually called a "surface".

Comment: For reflection across a sphere, where do you think the centre of the sphere should go?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3757047/472818

Answer (score 3):

Let (P) be the plane with equation

$$ax+by+cz=0$$

(I have dropped the $d$ but it can easily been included).

$N(a,b,c)$ be a normal vector to (P); we will assume WLOG that $\|N\|^2=a^2+b^2+c^2=1$.

Suppose one wants to reflect a surface with equation

$$f(x,y,z)=0\tag{1}$$

for example the sphere with center $(1,0,0)$ and unit radius

$$(x-1)^2+y^2+z^2-1=0\tag{2}$$

The symmetry $X \leftrightarrow X'$ with respect to plane (P) is obtained through the equation (see explanation below):

$$X'=(I_3-2 NN^T)X \ \ \iff  \ \ X=(I_3-2 NN^T)X' \tag{3}$$

(because symmetry is involutive ; N is assumed a column vector)

i.e., detailed in terms of coordinates:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\
y\\
z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}(1-2a^2)& -2ab&-2ac\\
-2ab&(1-2b^2)&-2bc \\
-2ac&-2bc&(1-2c^2)& \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x'\\
y'\\
z'\end{pmatrix}\tag{4}$$

It is enough now to replace $x,y,z$ in (1) by their expressions issued from (4) to get the equations of the symmetric surface.

For example, if you reflect the sphere with equation (2) into vertical plane with equation $x=0$ (meaning that $a=1$, $b=c=0$), you will get $x=-x',y=y',z=z'$, giving:

$$(x'+1)^2+y'^2+z'^2=1$$

**Remark:** If you want to symmetrize a straight line, consider it classically as the intersection of two planes, and symmetrize separately the equations of two planes using the method just seen.

**Explanation of formula (3):**

- the image of $X=N$ is $(I_3-2NN^T)N=N-2N\underbrace{(N^TN)}_{\|N\|^2=1}=-N$ as expected.
- if $M \perp N$, $(I_3-2NN^T)M=M-2N\underbrace{(N^TM)}_0=M$.

---

Edit: (following a remark of @mr_e_man):

in fact, one can "mirror" any geometrical object with respect to a circle in 2D or a sphere in 3D using a transformation called "inversion" which is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3599762). The mirroring property can be seen on the example of the fish "reflected" with respect to his bowl. A circle is in general reflected into a circle. For extended information and references, see [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2626356).

Comment: I think the question was not about reflecting a general surface across a plane, but about reflecting an object (such as a line) across a general surface.

Comment: @mr_e_man You are perfectly right. Frankly, I have misread the question. I must transform my text, in particular by saying that a solution exist for a symmetry wrt to a sphere by composing a symmetry with respect to a plane and "inversion transform" (which transforms a plane into a sphere)..

Comment: This answer and the matrix in (4) in particular was helpful for me while searching for a way to mirror 3D space on an arbitrary plane. Thanks!