# Difficulties with directed angles

Tags: geometry, contest-math

In most geometry books, I've studied with, it did not mention directed angles at all. Then I came across Evan Chen's EGMO which uses directed angles from the start to finish. Although he has written an explanation of the concept, I found directed angles quite cumbersome and confusing to understand. Is there a better way to visualise and understand directed angles so that it can seem more relatable when solving geometry problems because right now it seems more like an unnecessary and an extra step? And is it just me who's having trouble with it?

Comment: Directed angle is merely an angle where you know which is the "first" direction and which the "second" direction.

Comment: Are you familiar with vectors? A reasonable interpretation might be in terms of the cross product, where the sign of the resultant depends on whether you compute $x \times y$ or $y \times x$.

Comment: If you're not familiar with vectors, I think another way you can think about it is defining a natural orientation for angles. In the sense that if you view an angle from "right to left," when you are looking from the top onto the page, you have a positive angle. But if you look from the "bottom of the page," you have a negative angle. So it sort of defines a natural orientation that flips sign depending on whether you're looking into the page, or upwards through the bottom of the page

Comment: @AlanChung What do you mean by viewing an angle 'right to left' and when you say 'from the top/bottom' of the page? It's just that I've never come across this comparison before so I think I may need a little bit more of an in-depth explanation. 
Thank you

Comment: You surely accept that rotations are to be considered with a sign (for example, it is not the same to rotate axes in a $+\pi/4$ oreintation or in a $-\pi/4$ orientation). Then consider oriented angles as rotations.

Comment: Basically what I meant is the following. Suppose points A, B, C are on the plane, where X A is on the x axis, B is the origin, and C is in the first quadrant. Now, imagine rotating A counter-clockwise around B so that it eventually lies on the segment BC. Then, you're sweeping the segment AB around point B so that it lies on BC. 

You could also do the other way, where you rotate point C clockwise so that it eventually lies on segment AB (the x-axis). You can see that these two transformations sweep the same angle, but different directions (clockwise and counterclockwise)

Comment: The point here is that we usually define counter-clockwise is the "positive angle" direction (this is an arbitrary definition btw, we could very well have defined clockwise to be the positive direction). Thus, sweeping clockwise is sweeping through the same angle, but you're adding "negative degrees." 

What I meant by top and bottom of the page is the following. Imagine you draw the above configuration on a sheet of paper, and put it on top of a glass table. Now, imagine rotating point A counter-clockwise so that it eventually lies on BC.

Comment: Now, if you are looking from the ceiling down onto the paper, then you see that point A is rotating counter-clockwise. But suppose that you are lying on the floor and looking up at the paper. Then, you don't see that A is rotating counter-clockwise, it is actually rotating clockwise from that perspective! 

This means that looking from the floor up to the paper defines an "opposite orientation" as looking from the ceiling down to the paper. So the point of directed angle is to define an natural "orientation" for angles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer- didn't expect it to go that in depth :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem when studying EGMO, ad I wasted a lot of time, but the truth is, I didn't do what I should have done in the first place, that is just sit down and study directed angles till you understand it. It is really not a very difficult topic and I think if you just sit down and study it for some time (Only EGMO is needed, or maybe you could look at [this](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/Directed-Angles/Directed-Angles.pdf) handout by evan) instead of procrastinating (trust me, this is what is happening to you right now) you will soon understand it very well.

And I have to say is it needed very much, in a lot of problems (for instance see ISL 2019/G1) the only acceptable way to do that problem might be using directed angles, or when you will study inversion (ch-8), you will need directed angles a lot, for instance, my proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4609714/prove-that-inversion-preserves-angles-between-clines) is possible only because of directed angles.

But what I would say is you do not need directed right now that much, just do like the first 3 chapters using normal angles if you are not able to understand directed right now, and once you gain some geo experience, then sit down and just study directed angles and really try to understand it for like a couple hours or so, and then resolve some of the angle chasing problems from previous chapters using directed (at least that is what i did to understand directed angles).

Anyways,

All the best in your olympiad journey, and have fun!

Comment: Opps I hope I didn't see this too late.
But do you actually get marked down for not using directed angles in an actual olympiad or is it only if diagram dependence is an issue? I think the main thing I don't understand is why and how directed angles address the issue of diagram dependence. Maybe I need to study them more in depth. 
Thank you for your answer (P.s could you please upvote this question? I just need the reputations)

Comment: No, as far as i know, not using directed angles will probably never lose you marks, since you can just say wlog diagram is like this, but it does sometimes help you solve the problem though, for instance look at that G1/isl 19 which i had linked, when i tried this problem, i was originally using normal angles (i usually start of by using normal angles only) but was quite confused about whether I wanted to prove the angle was 'E' or '180-E' so I just used directed in which we can not care about 180 stuff. also, i upvoted :)

Comment: Just wondering, when you say ISL, do you mean the IMO Shortlist? To be honest, I don't even know if I can do questions from the ISL so I probably won't even get to the stage where you got confused with the angles cos I'll still be trying to figure out what the question is saying. But I'll still try. Also thank you for the upvote. -From NZ

Comment: Yeah I do mean ImoShortList,what i will say to you is like just trust that you can do the problems and just work hard and do not give up easily, and soon you will start solving them. this is the advice people had given me when i was starting out especially for combo, but i did not listen to them and i thought i could never do combo, which was the biggest mistake ever because after a long time (like two years) of solving basically zero combo problems, i just decided to work on a few and suddenly solved 2 problems, so it was kinda sad to imagine how much more i could have done if i wasn't scared

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best definition of a *direct* (or *oriented*) angle of vector half lines is to establish a bijection with plane rotations, following the comments of @Jean Marie and @David G. Stork.

$\tt Definition\;1\quad$ A vector half line in the 2-dimensional (real) vector space $E\,$ is a subset of $E$ of the form

$$ \Delta := \mathbb R_+\,v = \left\{\lambda v\;:\;\lambda\geq0\right\}\qquad (\text{with } v\neq 0). $$

A **direct angle of half lines** $\,$(or simply **angle**)$\;\theta\,$ in $E\,$ is an *ordered* pair of half lines, which we will denote by

$$ \theta := (\Delta_1,\Delta_2)^\wedge. $$

Two angles $\,\theta=(\Delta_1, \Delta_2)^\wedge,\; \theta'=(\Delta'_1, \Delta'_2)^\wedge$ of an euclidean space $E$ are equal iff, by definition, there is a rotation of $E$, i.e. an element $\varrho$ of the group $\mathbb{SO}(E)$, such that

$$ \varrho(\Delta_1)=\Delta'_1\qquad\text{and}\qquad \varrho(\Delta_2)=\Delta'_2. $$

The set $\;\cal U\;$ of equivalence classes of equal angles is in a bijection with the group $\mathbb{SO}(E)$, so is itself a group, called the **group of angles of E**. These groups are therefore isomorphic, and are denoted additively the first and multiplicatively the second. They are also commutative because dim(E)=2. The isomorphism

$$ ρ\;:\;\mathcal U\;\longrightarrow\;\mathbb{SO}(E) $$

associates to each class $[\theta]$ of equal angles the corresponding rotation.

It is interesting to point out that, despite its name, an oriented angle does **not** depends on any orientation of $E$: it can be viewed as a simple *function* $\;E\longrightarrow E\;$ with the constraint of being a rotation carrying a given half line onto another given half line.

But, what about the common notion of an angle as a set of points (or vectors in our case) between two half lines? After all, we are fond of this vision of angle. To do this, however, the plane must be oriented, otherwise there would be ambiguity in the choice of the point/vectors to be considered. In fact we can describe $\theta=(\Delta_1, \Delta_2)^\wedge$ by "going" from $\Delta_1$ to $\Delta_2$ in one direction or the opposite, thus obtaining explementary angles. We can proceed in the following way.

$\tt Definition\; 2\quad$ An **orientation** over the vector space $\,E\;$ is a non zero alternating bilinear form

$$ \Psi\;:\;E\times E \;\longrightarrow\; \mathbb R. $$

This orientation form distinguishes positively and negatively oriented bases of $\,E\;$ according to the sign it takes on the given bases. The space $\,E\;$ equipped with an orientation form $\Psi$ is called an **oriented vector space**.

$\tt Definition\;3\quad$ Let $\Delta_1=\mathbb R_+v_1,\;\; \Delta_2=\mathbb R_+v_2, \;$ with $v_1, v_2\neq0$.
The **open angular sector** associated with the angle $\theta=(\Delta_1, \Delta_2)^\wedge$ of the oriented vector space $\,E\;$ is the set

$$ S^°(\theta) = S^°(\Delta_1, \Delta_2) := \left\{v\in E\raise.3ex\smallsetminus\{0\}\;:\;\rm{pos}\Big(\Psi(v_1, v), \Psi(v, v_2), \Psi(v_2, v_1)\Big)\geq2\right\}, $$

where $\;\rm{pos}(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)\;$  denote the numbers of strictly positive elements contained into the round parenthesis.

It isn't difficult to check, by some pictures for example, that this definition corresponds to our intuitive idea of angle as a set of points, and that it depends, obviously, on chosen orientation.

**Affine case**$\quad$ What has been said so far is easily transposed to affine planes, which is the natural setting of classical plane geometry.

Let $\mathcal A(E)$ be an affine real plane with $E$ as the vector space of translations. Given three points $V, A_1, A_2$ of $\mathcal A(E)$ with $A_1$ and $A_2\neq V$, the **angle** of vertex $V$ passing through $A_1$ and $A_2$ is a triple $(V;\Delta_1, \Delta_2)^\wedge$, where, for $i=1,2$:

$$ \Delta_i=\big\{P\in \mathcal A(E)\;:\;P-V=\lambda(A_i-V) \;\text{ for some } \lambda\geq0\big\}=
$$

$$ =V+\mathbb R_+(A_i-V). $$

The space $\mathcal A(E)$ is oriented if such is $E$. The **open angular sector** associated with the angle $(V;A_1,A_2)^\wedge$ of the oriented affine space $\mathcal A(E)$ is the set

$$ S^°(V;A_1,A_2) := \hskip8cm $$
$$ :=\Big\{P\in \mathcal A(E)\;:\;\rm{pos}\Big(\Psi(A_1-V, P-V), \Psi(P-V, A_2-V), \Psi(A_2-V, A_1-V)\Big)\geq 2\Big\}. $$

As can be seen, the affine case reduces to the vector case, where the vectors all apply to the vertex $V$.