# The proof of a formula for solving Japanese Sangaku Problem

Tags: geometry

This came from the question:

> When the raidus of the outermost (green) circle is $10$, can you find
> the radii of the first $5$ yellow circles (from the largest)?

[image]

And according to this [article](http://www.mrmillermath.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/100SangakuHistory.pdf), it can be solved by this formula:

$$\frac{r}{(2n-1)^2 + 14}$$

I'm interested in seeing the proof of this formula above and by the way also it's not clear (from the article) what $r$ and $n$ are for. I'm assuming the $r$ is the radii of the green circle and $n$ is the radii of the yellow circles. I've tried to search the proof but I couldn't find it. I'm also not able to prove because I don't know where I start.

Update: I tried to check the usability of the formula by drawing this triangle $ABC$ :

[image]

I got $1/3$ when I plug $r=5$ and $n=1$. It seems to be work (I'm still not sure because I might be wrong though). I want to compare if the double area by using Heron's formula is the same as the area when I use the regular triangle formula ($1/2\cdot b\cdot h$) by finding the red line first by using Pythagorean first. And it seems equal. I labeled them $z$ and $y$ respectively. Here's the calculation:

[image]

Comment: Once you have the radius of the red circles, you can (as the article suggests) apply [Descartes' "Kissing Circles" Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem) a few times. The caption for the cover image mentions, "[The sangaku] asks for the radius of the $n$th largest blue circle in terms of $r$, the radius of the green circle." So, the solution won't match your stated problem of finding the radius of a yellow circle. Nevertheless, Descartes' theorem will still be helpful.)

Comment: @Blue new update. I have tried the formula and it seems to be match. I try to draw a triangle woth the points lie on the center of the yellow, the tangency of two red circle and the center of the red circle. It has the same area when I use heron's formula compared to the usual pythagoras when finding the length between rhe tangency and the center of the yellow circle.

Comment: A radius of $1/3=0.333\ldots$ for the first yellow circle would make it quite small compare to the red circles of radii $5$, which doesn't *look* correct. By coincidence, the radius of the first yellow circle is $r/3$; the next four are $r/6$, $r/11$, $r/18$, $r/27$. Since the denominator of article's formula is always greater than $14$, that formula certainly cannot yield the first few values. But, then, it isn't supposed to. On the other hand, the first blue radius is $r/15$, which matches the formula, as appropriate.

Comment: In the question it mentions, *radius* of green circle is $10$. But in your attempt, it seems you're taking *diameter* $=10$.

Comment: This is a particular case of a [Pappus chain](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2627362). The simplest approach is to use inversion.

Comment: @MyMolecules Lol. I'm an idiot. I didn't realize that, sorry.